# Lebesgue Measure on sets on the circumference of a circle

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

This is a homework question.  Suppose we have a construction of Lebesgue measure for (closed, open and half-open) intervals.  Is there any way to apply this construction to a construction of Lebesgue measure for sets on the circumference of a circle?  I was thinking of finding a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to a circle, but from the comments I think this is not the right way to go about it.

If not then could somebody kindly provide a hint on construction a Lebesgue measure on sets on the circumference of a circle?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with a bijection, for example, let $x$ in the half-open interval $[0,2\pi)$ correspond to $e^{ix}$ on the unit circle in the complex plane, and define the measure of a subset $S$ of the circle to be the measure of its inverse image in the interval.

Comment: okay thank you, if you write as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Let me encourage you to write it up and post it as an answer (since it's your homework, after all).

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \subset [0,2\pi)$ and take $S$ a subset of the unit circle in the complex plane $S \subset \mathcal{C}$, and put

$$ f(x) = e^{ix}$$

s.t.

$$ f: [0,2\pi) \to \mathcal{C} $$

Let $\mu$ be a constructed measure on half-open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$, then $\mu (x)$ is measurable; so if we take the inverse image on $S \subset \mathcal{C}$ we have a mapping to $[0,2\pi)$ such that the measure on the circle is measurable as well, ie

$$ f^{-1}(S) \subset x $$

$$ \Rightarrow \mu(f^{-1}(S)) \leq \mu(x) $$

With

$$ v(S) \equiv \mu(f^{-1}(S)) $$

Next we want to show $v$ is a Lebesgue measure, that is

$$ v(S) = v(S \cap E) + v(S \cap E^c) $$

Where $E \subset \mathcal{C}$ for every $S \in \mathcal{C}$

We clearly have $S = (S \cap E) \cup (S \cap E^c)$ then by countable subadditivity of $\mu$

$$ \mu(f^{-1}(S)) \leq \mu(f^{-1}(S \cap E)) + \mu(f^{-1} (S \cap E^c)) $$

For the other direction suppose $\{B_n\}, \{C_n\}$ are any finite or countable system of rectangles covering $f^{-1}(S \cap E)$ and $f^{-1}(S \cap E^c)$, respectively then we can put

$$ \mu(f^{-1}(S \cap E)) \leq \sum_n \mu(B_n) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}  $$

and

$$ \mu(f^{-1}(S \cap E^c)) \leq \sum_n \mu(C_n) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} $$

Add these two lines to have

$$ \mu(f^{-1}(S \cap E)) + \mu(f^{-1}(S \cap E^c)) \leq \sum_n \mu(B_n) + \sum_n \mu(C_n) + \varepsilon $$

Since this has to hold for all $\varepsilon$ ... we must somehow have

$$ \sum_n \mu(B_n) + \sum_n \mu(C_n) \leq \mu(f^{-1}(S))$$

Comment: Good start. But $\mu([0,2\pi))$ is just a number, right? so it doesn't make much sense to say it's measurable. Also, we're trying to define a measure on the circle, so what we're aiming for is something like $\nu(S)=\mu(f^{-1}(S))$.

Comment: Okay thank you, so it should be $\mu(x)$, but I don't know how connect $v(S)$ with $\mu(f^{-1}(S))$

Comment: We need a name for the measure we're constructing on the circle, so I've called it $\nu$. Then for a subset $S$ of the circle, we need to know how to compute $\nu(S)$. So we first apply $f^{-1}$ to $S$, to get us back to a subset of $[0,2\pi)$, and then we can apply $\mu$ to that subset. So, we can define $\nu(S)$ to be $\mu(f^{-1}(S))$. Then you just have to prove it works.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you, I appreciate you being so patient with me, I'm trying my best, but I don't think I can get a proper proof; this just doesn't come naturally to me as you can tell (:

Comment: Maybe it's best to make an appointment to see your teacher. Just a few small things I noticed: for $x\subset[0,2\pi)$ I think you mean $x\in[0,2\pi)$. This makes $x$ a number, so $\mu(x)=0$, so you don't really mean to say $\mu(x)$ is measurable. The adjective "measurable" doesn't apply to numbers, and it doesn't apply to measures; it applies to (some) subsets of $[0,2\pi)$. And then the point is that any subset $S$ of the circle whose inverse image is a measurable subset of $[0,2\pi)$ becomes a measurable subset of the circle by defining its measure $\nu(S)$ by $\nu(S)=\mu(f^{-1}(S))$.

Comment: But, really, see your teacher.